# Managing and storing AES keys in a webserver application

Tags: encryption, web-applications, aes

I have a webserver application which receives uploaded files, encrypts and decrypts them using AES256. I encrypted them so a potential hacker, who somehow got into the storage, can't do anything with the files. At the moment every file is being encrypted using the same hard-coded key.

Is it more secure to encrypt every file with an other random key stored in a database, maybe hashed (and salted, too)? Does this even provide a higher level of security? Or can it be worse to store such keys in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

key storage is a rather fundamental problem and hard to solve without rather special hardware.

as long as you store the keys on same machine as the encrypted data, an attacker will get both. that doesn't fundamentally change if you just have more keys.

you can't hash / salt the keys either, as hashing is a one-way function and with just the stored hash you yourself (or your app) would not be able to compute the key, so this is pointless.

if practicable, you could enter the key manually when the app server starts, so the key just lives in RAM, not on disk. make sure it doesn't get paged out to swap partition.

if you could encrypt the files clientside (before upload), so only the user has the keys, that would be safer...